# How to deploy ember-cli app to S3

Tags: ember.js, amazon-s3, ember-cli

I have an ember-cli app that is deployed in S3. It works well, and I have Travis set up to deploy changes when there is a merge into the master branch in GitHub.

But sometimes I want to test a change in the deployment environment without a commit -- perhaps because it can only be tested in that environment, like a fix to a mobile-only defect.

So I tried:

```
ember build --environment=production
```

followed by:

```
aws s3 cp dist/ s3://my_bucket/ --recursive
```

which uploaded things to my bucket. But the page didn't work, my browser told me there was a redirect loop. It wasn't a code issue, because when I pushed the changes to master, Travis successfully deployed them to S3.

Is there something clearly wrong with what I did, copying the `dist` folder to my bucket?

I'm using Ember-cli 1.3.1, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use ember-cli-deploy works pretty and support several plugin in order deliver your code much more easier.

I haven been using it for a while a work pretty well.

http://ember-cli.github.io/ember-cli-deploy/plugins/

Comment: I could use a plugin, but since I almost always deploy with Travis, I was hoping to just understand what I'm doing incorrectly.